# PhpStorm (IntelliJ IDEA) is not detecting changes to files

Tags: intellij-idea, synchronization, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've configured TypeScript compiler to watch for changes in source files and to recompile the project externally (`tsc --watch`). However, when I open compiled file in the PhpStorm, it's not updated when changed. I can either force it to update using `Synchornize` command, or by changing the focus from PhpStorm window.

Here's the video: https://youtu.be/qpOsaPYNcws.

**How do I make PhpStorm to detect filesystem changes and to update opened files dynamically, like Visual Studio Code does?**

Comment: So ... how do you run TypeScript compiler? Is it run outside of IDE .. or built-in ... or as File Watcher (IDE functionality)? In general -- if file is modified outside of IDE (e.g. 3rd party app running in background) then IDE does not see such changes unless Synchronize is used or app looses/gains focus (that's when IDE runs Synchronize as well, unless disabled in Settings). Therefore ideal way is to use any built-in functionality.

Comment: P.S. I've added `WebStorm` tag as it's more JS/TS oriented tool than PhpStorm while having the same functionality.

Comment: I'm running `tsc --watch` in a separate shell. I don't want to use IDE for this purpose, cause different developers could use different IDEs.

Comment: You can use File Watcher -- it will run your command/program on file save (e.g. `tsc --compile /path/to/file` -- not the right syntax but just to give you an idea). If configured properly it will know what generated files to refresh. Official general manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm . Other than that it's a "file modified by app running in background case" P.S. You may record a macro that will do Save and then Synchronize ... but it could be too fast (file may not yet be compiled yet) so it's not solid solution either.

Comment: Lets see what JetBrains people can say about it. Considering the layout (generated file is opened in another editor tab) I would expect this to be refreshed (checked for external modifications) in any case....